# Loop through numbers in a string (numbers only)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to highlight the 4th, 5th and 6th number of a string by wrapping a `<span>` tag around it. The string contains numbers, commas, a dollar sign and occasionally dots.

Here's my string:

```
"$116,023,150"
```

I want the output exactly the same, except the 4th, 5th and 6th number are wrapped inside `<span>` tags. I've tried using looping through the string using a `for()` loop. However, I don't want the any other character to influence the count (only the numbers in the string).

```
"$116,<span>0</span><span>2</span><span>3</span>,150"
```

Let's say the string would be different, I still want to have the 4th, 5th and 6th number wrapped in a `<span>` tag.

```
"$61,0<span>0</span><span>2</span>.<span>1</span>2" == "$61,002.12"
```

How can I achieve this with Javascript / jQuery?

Comment: have you tried using `Number.isInteger(value)` ?

Comment: It's really unclear what merits wrapping in a `span` tag. Can you show more examples? Or is it just the fact that they are the 4th-6th in the string?

Comment: How about `String#split` ?

Comment: what if string was `$16,023,150` ... criteria is vague. Also what research have you done and what code have you tried to resolve this with yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a regex with a replacement function, where depending on the "index" of the digit, it get's wrapped in `<span>` tags. (Not really the index, it's the current count of digits up to that digit)

```js
$("div").html(function(_, old) {
  var i = 0;
  return old.replace(/\d/g, function(num) {
    i++;
    return i >= 4 && i <= 6 ? "<span>" + num + "</span>" : num;
  });
});
```

```css
span { font-weight: bold }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>$116,023,150</div>
<div>$61,002.12</div>
```